# In Pricebook Entry validation rule I am not able to access the Pricebook fields

Tags: community, fields, pricebook, pricebookentry

I am trying to create validation rule under Pricebook entry object.
In that I am not able to access the Pricebook field, we have standard lookup "Pricebook" field in Pricebook Entry.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it is not being shown in the fields, but you can reference it simply by writing 'Pricebook2.' + the field name.

For instnace:

```
Pricebook2.Name == 'MyPriceBook1'
```